# How to add a card to a Metabase dashboard using Python

Tags: python, rest, metabase

I've extracted ordered cards from a *Metabase* dashboard and would like to copy them into a new empty dashboard through Python.

I don't find the [Metabase API documentation: Add Card to Dashboard](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/api-documentation.html#post-apidashboardidcards) particularly clear:

> POST `/api/dashboard/:id/cards`
>
> with the following parameters:
>
> - **id**,
> - **cardId** value may be nil, or if non-nil, value must be an integer greater than zero
> - **parameter_mappings** value must be an array. Each value must be a map.
> - **series**
> - **dashboard-card**

I have no idea what goes in each of these parameters and the documentation doesn't seem to explain it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To post a card by a given card id (for example card with id 201) I am using the following payload:

```
payload_to_post = {
    "cardId": 201,
    "sizeX": 4,
    "sizeY": 4,
    "col": 8,
    "row": 0,
    "dashboard-card": {"card_id": 201},
}
```

This will add a 4x4 card with id 201 on dashboard with id :id on row 0 and column 8.